# Using multiple select statements in CTE i- snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I’m using 3 CTE’s in my SNOWFLAKE SQL
query.

Using CTE 1 to query CTE 2 and CTE 3 and then joining CTE 2 and CTE 3 for Result 2

Eg.
CTE 1 = Result 1
CTE 2 join CTE 3 = Result 2

Now I want to use select statements to display Result 1 and Result 2.

Which is not possible to have two select statements while using CTE. What is the alternative method to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to post the SQL you are attempting. The description is unclear on what you need to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `union` to accomplish this.

```
with 
  result1 as (select my_field from table1),
  result2 as (select table2.myfield 
              from table2
              inner join table 3 on table2.key = table3.key
              ),
  unioned as (
              select 'res1' as source, * from result1
              union all
              select 'res2' as source, * from result2
             )
select * from unioned
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to use views instead of CTEs:

```sql
create or replace view step1 
as
select *
from table1
;

create or replace view step2
as 
select *
from step1 a
join table2 b
on a.x = b.x
;
```

Then you can get both `select * from step1` and `select * from step2` to see the results.